# How to set up a server to use TLS-SRP authentication?

Tags: ssl

How to get it work at all?

I used [this manual](http://web.archive.org/web/20111018150520/http://trustedhttp.org/wiki/TLS-SRP_in_OpenSSL). I created a verifier file and started `openssl s_server` with a self-signed RSA certificate. Now I can't connect to it.

```
>gnutls-cli --srpusername user --srppasswd secret 127.0.0.1 -p 4433 --insecure
Processed 145 CA certificate(s).
Resolving '127.0.0.1'...
Connecting to '127.0.0.1:4433'...
*** Fatal error: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
*** Received alert [40]: Handshake failed
No certificates found!
*** Handshake has failed
GnuTLS error: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
```

Curl seems not to work too, but win32 binaries doesn't have SRP in `"Features:"` output from `curl -V`

Even `openssl s_client` stops working as far as I add `-cipher SRP` param.

```
openssl s_server -srpvfile xx.srp -tls1 -cipher SRP -cert ssl.crt -key ssl.key -www
```

-

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000750)
2672:error:1407745B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1115):.\ssl\s23_c
lnt.c:741:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 321 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

What now?

I'm using latest versions (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, gnutls-3.0.22-w32, latest curl win32 build).

How should SRP accounts be registered?

**Please add a tag for TLS-SRP**

Comment: How are you starting the server, and does your OpenSSL version even support TLS-SRP? (≥ 1.0.1)

Comment: Just read the manual. I use latest OpenSSL (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013).

Answer (score 8):

These instructions worked for me using openssl 1.0.1e compiled on win32.

Step 1. create empty SRP password file passwd.txt

Step 2. Add a user to the SRP password file

```
openssl srp -srpvfile passwd.txt -userinfo "This is Myself" -add myself
Enter pass phrase for myself:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for myself:
```

Step 3. Start SRP server

```
openssl s_server -nocert -cipher SRP -srpvfile passwd.txt -accept 444
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
ACCEPT
```

Step 4. Connect to server

```
openssl s_client -srpuser myself -cipher SRP -connect localhost:444
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000108)
Enter pass phrase for SRP user:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2407 bytes and written 1184 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
    Session-ID: 69AE0C7ED831DCCDA0E79CB5ED55E0BF9C65CA64B4077585CF9DD93CEE611358
```

Comment: Well, this seem to work. Gratulate you to be the first at all who paid attention to this question! But! 1. Seems OpenSSL creates by default 8 kbit verifier, it's a little bit too long, 1.5-2 kbit should be enough. How to do this? There is a -gN parameter, what does it do? 2. How to use this outside of openssl console tool? Even gnutls example from the manual fails.

Comment: Hey! Come back please!

Comment: Hi @disk eater, I follow your instruction for Openssl version 1.0.1f. we need to remove the '-nocert' option in server setup and create the server.pem file